# converting sms text to speech in android

Tags: android, text-to-speech

I have following code.
first code get text from Edittext and convert to voice.
and second code is getting sms text from inbox.
my project is converting sms text to voice.
how can make relation ship between two code and use 2 activity?

please help me.
code for get text from edittext is:

```
package com.prgguru.android;
import java.util.Locale;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech;
import android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech.OnInitListener;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class TexttoSpeechActivity extends Activity implements OnInitListener {
    private TextToSpeech tts;
    private Button btnSpeak;
    private EditText txtText;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        tts = new TextToSpeech(this, this);
        btnSpeak = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSpeak);
        txtText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtText);

        btnSpeak.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                speakOut();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        // Don't forget to shutdown!
        if (tts != null) {
            tts.stop();
            tts.shutdown();
        }
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    public void onInit(int status) {
        if (status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {
            int result = tts.setLanguage(Locale.US);
            if (result == TextToSpeech.LANG_MISSING_DATA || result == TextToSpeech.LANG_NOT_SUPPORTED) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Language not supported", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Log.e("TTS", "Language is not supported");
            } else { btnSpeak.setEnabled(true); }
        } else { Log.e("TTS", "Initilization Failed"); }
    }

    private void speakOut() {
        String text = txtText.getText().toString();
        if (text.length() == 0) {
            tts.speak("You haven't typed text", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
        } else {
            tts.speak(text, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
        }
    }
}
```

code for getting sms text from inbox is?

```
 package com.android.www;

 import android.app.Activity;
 import android.content.Intent;
 import android.database.Cursor;
 import android.net.Uri;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.widget.TextView;
 import android.widget.Toast;

 public class smstext extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    TextView view = new TextView(this);
    Uri uriSMSURI = Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox");
    Cursor cur =getContentResolver().query(uriSMSURI, null, null, null, null);
    String sms="";
    while (cur.moveToNext()){
        sms +="From:"+ cur.getString(2)+":"+cur.getString(11)+"\n";
    }
    view.setText(sms);
    setContentView(view);


   }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

http://pulse7.net/android/read-sms-message-inbox-sent-draft-android/ Also has code for drafts and sent boxes.

```
// Create Inbox box URI
Uri inboxURI = Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox");

// List required columns
String[] reqCols = new String[] { "_id", "address", "body" };

// Get Content Resolver object, which will deal with Content Provider
ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();

// Fetch Inbox SMS Message from Built-in Content Provider
Cursor c = cr.query(inboxURI, reqCols, null, null, null);
```